# StartActivity() crashes the application

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to send data between activities, this is the sending code:

```
  public void sendToFavorites(Context context){
        String vID,vThumbnail,vTitle;
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();

        vID = sendResult.getId().getVideoId();
        vThumbnail = sendResult.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getMedium().getUrl();
        vTitle = sendResult.getSnippet().getTitle();
        extras.putString("id",vID);

        intent = new Intent(context,Favorites.class);
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(intent); <----- Application crash here.
}
```

This is the logcat:

```
05-18 18:39:00.560  28528-28528/project.youtubeplayer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: project.youtubeplayer, PID: 28528
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984)
        at project.youtubeplayer.MainActivity.sendToFavorites(MainActivity.java:183)
        at project.youtubeplayer.YtAdapter$1.onClick(YtAdapter.java:77)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Calling to sendToFavroites:

```
        mHolder.mVideoFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AppUtils.showToast(result.getSnippet().getTitle() + " Was added to favorites.");
            m.sendResult = result;
            m.sendToFavorites(mActivity);
        }
    });
```

YtAdapter:

```
public class YtAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity mActivity = null;
private List<SearchResult> mVideoList = null;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = null;
MainActivity m = new MainActivity();

public YtAdapter(Activity iActivity){
    mActivity = iActivity;
    mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity);
}
public void setmVideoList(List<SearchResult> mVideoList){
    this.mVideoList = mVideoList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return (mVideoList == null)? (0):(mVideoList.size());
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return (mVideoList != null && mVideoList.size()>position)? (mVideoList.get(position)):(null);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder mHolder;
    if(convertView != null){
        mHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }else{
        mHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_video_item,null);
        mHolder.mVideoThumbnail = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_thumbnail);
        mHolder.mVideoTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_title);
        mHolder.mVideoFavorite = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_favorite);

        convertView.setTag(mHolder);
    }
    //Setting the data
    final SearchResult result = mVideoList.get(position);
    mHolder.mVideoTitle.setText(result.getSnippet().getTitle());

    //Loading the image
    Picasso.with(mActivity).load(result.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getMedium().getUrl()).into(mHolder.mVideoThumbnail);

    //OnClickListeners
    mHolder.mVideoFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AppUtils.showToast(result.getSnippet().getTitle() + " Was added to favorites.");
            m.sendResult = result;
            m.sendToFavorites(mActivity);
        }
    });

    mHolder.mVideoThumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AppUtils.showToast("Please click on title to start video");
        }
    });
    return  convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder{
    private TextView mVideoTitle = null;
    private ImageView mVideoThumbnail = null;

    //Testing
    private ImageView mVideoFavorite = null;
}
```

From MainActivity calling YtAdapter:

```
    @Override
public void completedRequest(Object... objects){
    //Dismiss the dialog
    if(mLoadingDialog != null && mLoadingDialog.isShowing())
        mLoadingDialog.dismiss();

    //Parse the response based on type of request
    Integer reqCode = (Integer) objects[0];
    if(reqCode == null || reqCode == 0)
        throw  new NullPointerException("Request Code's value is Invalid.");
    switch (reqCode){
        case SEARCH_VIDEO:
            if(mYtadapter == null){
                mYtadapter = new YtAdapter(this);
                mYtadapter.setmVideoList((List<SearchResult>)objects[1]);
                mVideoLsv.setAdapter(mYtadapter);
            }else{
                mYtadapter.setmVideoList((List<SearchResult>) objects[1]);
                mYtadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

I tried to search the net for that problem but couldn't find any answers..
Hope you guys could help me.

Comment: are you doing this inside a fragment or an activity?

Comment: where are you calling `sendToFavorites(Context context)` from and what value you are passing? Check if that value is `null`

Comment: @AndyJoyce Activity.

Comment: @Mithun I'm calling sendToFavorites from YtAdapter ( I will edit the post and add it in a minute )

Comment: Try using `getApplicationContext()` in your intent.

Comment: Can you post the Activity code where you call that Adapter?

Comment: @MikeKeepsOnShine Edited again.

Comment: Why are you doing `MainActivity m = new MainActivity();`, ?? Try modifying your constructor `public YtAdapter(MainActivity iActivity)`, change your instance variable to `private MainActivity mActivity = null;` see if it helps. Since you are using `mActivity instanceOf MainActivity` you can directly call its methods, such as `sendToFavorites`

Comment: Oh good grief...I just spotted what you're trying to do...`MainActivity m = new MainActivity();`. You can *NOT* create a valid instance of an `Activity` using `new`. You shouls also *NEVER* create `public` methods in an `Activity` with the intention of calling them from other classes.

Comment: Didn't I say it?? :D

Comment: @Mithun : I was still typing when you posted your comment.

Comment: @Mithun Thank you both, Can You please give me example or even edit my code ? My english is not my native tounge and im getting a little confused.

Comment: @Mithun Thanks ! I will update as soon as possible!

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

In the `activity`, define the `context`

```
final Context context = this;
```

The use it in the `adapter` instead of the `activity`.

```
m.sendToFavorites(context);
```

So, in the `adapter`, define `Context cxt`;

```
public YtAdapter(Context _cxt){
 ....
 cxt = _cxt;
}
```

Then use it like following:

```
intent = new Intent(cxt,Favorites.class);
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        cxt.startActivity(intent);
```

I walk this way when i use an `adapter`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, should I do it in MainActivity?

Comment: You do it in the activity in which you call the adapter. According to the code that you did post, yes.